# Java OutOfMemory only in Linux environment

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I am fighting against a strange OutOfMemory error in my Java Web App.

**My dev environment:**

- Windows 7
- Java 7
- Tomcat 8 with '-Xms64m -Xmx1024m' arguments.

**My test environment:**

- Linux Ubuntu EC2 Amazon Instance (2gb RAM)
- Java 7
- Tomcat 7 with '-Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -server' arguments.

I can test my app on my dev environment without any problem, but on my test environment I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

I cannot replicate the errors because in my dev environment (with less memory than my linux) does not throw the OutOfMemoryError.

Tell me if need some extra information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggest you modify your dev environment to match test to attempt to replicate the error.  Start with the easy stuff like changing your vm arguments to match, then try with Tomcat 7, etc

Comment: But in my win dev the vm arguments are lower than test env. Logic says that should crash more than test env..

Comment: It's still helpful to remove environment variances when attempting to reproduce an error condition.  If your dev environment doesn't replicate the error and test does, you could try changing test to match -- it's very possible that the real issue is that test doesn't have 1536MB of contiguous free memory to allocate

Answer (score 0):

You have an EC instance with a total memory of 2GB and give 1536MB to your java process, and that as the initial heap size. You probably do not have that much free memory for your process, because the linux system itself needs memory, and other processes that might be running as well.

Try to reduce the memory for example to `-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m`, if this is running you could try to increase it in smaller steps, but does your process really need all this memory?